# Suppose $n>m$, $A$ is a $m\times n $ matrix with $\operatorname{rank} A =m$, $B$ is a $n\times (n-m)$ matrix, $\operatorname{rank} B= n-m$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $n>m$, $A$ is a $m\times n $ matrix with $\operatorname{rank} A =m$, $B$ is a $n\times (n-m)$ matrix, $\operatorname{rank} B= n-m$. And we already have $AB=0$. $\alpha$ is a vector satisfy $A\alpha=0$. Prove there exists a vector $\gamma$ such that $\alpha=B\gamma$.

I tried to write $A$ in terms of column vectors.
$$A=\{A_1,A_2,\cdots,A_n\}$$
then $B$ is kind of combination of solutions to $AX=0$.
Now what we want to prove is write a solution in terms of other solution's combination.  Don't know how to continue from this...

Comment: You know that the image of $B$ has dimension $n-m$, that the kernel of $A$ has dimension $n-m$, and that the first is inside the second, because $AB=0$. Therefore, both are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

You don't even need to consider elements: $AB=0$ means $\;\operatorname{Im}B\subset \ker A$.

Now the rank-nullity theorem asserts that 
$$\dim \ker A= n -\operatorname{rank}A=n-m$$

Can you conclude?

Comment: Since $Im B \subset ker A$, and $\dim ker A=n-m= \dim Im B$, hence $ker A = Im B$. Now $\alpha \in ker A = Im B$, then there exists a vector $\gamma$ such that $\alpha =B\gamma $

Comment: It's exactly that.